# Cannot modify UIButton events

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton

In my app a button has its "Touch Up Inside" event associated to a method. Method gets executed as expected. After a year same button's events are revised, and now no event changes in Connection Inspector has any effect. Same method still gets executed after "Touch Up Inside" event association is deleted. No new events works.

What has happened?
Xcode 4 has been replaced with Xcode 5.1 meanwhile.

Regards

Comment: put your method code.

Answer (score 0):

No changes made in the interface builder had any effect on the view. By completely removing XIB and deleting workspace cache still kept the view unchanged. Had to recreate the viewcontroller incl. XIB to overcome this xcode bug.